# Cycle with exception in bash

Tags: bash, wildcards

How to write a cycle pro all files *.py except a.py?

```
for i in *.py && !(a.py); do 
    python3 $i
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [extended globs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Extended_Globs) (`shopt extglob` set in Bash), `!(a).py` should match all filenames ending in `.py`, except for `a.py`:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls 
a.py  bar.py  foo.py  foo.txt
$ echo !(a).py
bar.py foo.py
```

But you could also just exclude that one file manually with a test, this wouldn't need any Bash-specific features:

```
for f in ./*.py; do
    [ "$f" = a.py ] && continue
    python "$f"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much